# Issue displaying images inline

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a number of images on the same line without wrapping down. I have tried  just about everything I know to make this work with no luck! I am trying to make an image selector for a slideshow that will be loaded into the page with ajax / jQuery and I don't want it to take up a ton of screen realestate. Ideally I want to be able to scroll horizontally and select my images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function () {
      test();
    });     

    function test(){
      for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
        $("#test").append("<img src='"+images[i]+"' style='width:250px; height: 250px; margin:10px; display:inline'/>");
      };
    } 
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Usually I have 0 issues with HTML so I feel kind of silly for asking and I'm sure it's a very simple mistake I am making. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error is occuring when you run it, what needs to be fixed?

Comment: The images are being wrapped down to the next line still

Comment: Im not getting this, what you have done is fine...see http://jsfiddle.net/6EUb2/2/

Comment: In every browser I try it does this: [link](http://imgur.com/K1Jsr)

Comment: See Matvey Andreyev answer, thats what your after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try applying nowrap to div#test:

```
#test{ white-space:nowrap; }
```

You may also need another wrapper around div#test with overflow:auto; then if you want the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try float:left in the images or try to wrap the images in a div and then try float:left

Answer (score 0):

Try `float:left` in the `<img>` tags style. If it doesn't help, try changing `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

try `float:left` on images
and I see that you haven't declared the images array(hope you have in your original code)